# Deriving the formula $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ from the geometric property of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose we are given that the determinant satisfies the following property for any $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$: $$\widehat{\operatorname{vol}}(\alpha (X))=\det A\cdot\operatorname{vol}(X).$$ Here $\alpha\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is any linear operator which under any fixed basis yields the matrix $A$. Further $\widehat{\operatorname{vol}}(\alpha (X))$ represents the signed volume, i.e. it is the volume with the negative sign if $\alpha$ involves reflection. $\operatorname{vol}(X)$ represents the ordinary volume.

Now we wish to show that for any two matrices $A,B$ we have $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. To that end we let $\alpha,\beta$ be the operators corresponding with $A,B$ and for any set $X$ with nonzero volume and note that $$\det(AB).\operatorname{vol}(X)=\widehat{\operatorname{vol}}(\alpha\beta (X))=\det A\cdot\operatorname{vol}(\beta X)$$

Now I would like that $\det A\cdot\operatorname{vol}(\beta X)=\det A\cdot\det B\cdot\operatorname{vol}(X)$ so that cancelling out $\operatorname{vol}(X)$ we get that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ as required. My problem is that $\operatorname{vol}(\beta X)\ne\det B\cdot\operatorname{vol}(X)$ in general as $\operatorname{vol}(\beta X)$ represents the ordinary volume and not signed volume.

What am I missing here?

Comment: at least state why you downvote something, yes, now i see there were absolutes missing and it doesnt work.

Comment: You already need $$\widehat{\operatorname{vol}}(\alpha(X)) = \det A\cdot \widehat{\operatorname{vol}}(X)$$ in the first equation. Without an orientation of $X$, how is an orientation of $\alpha(X)$ determined?

Comment: @DanielFischer: The orientation of $\alpha(X)$ is reversed if $X$ is turned inside out under action by $\alpha$ by reflection. I do not know of a rigorous definition of orientation. If you would correct me I would be obliged.

Comment: @DanielFischer: X is a subset without any orientation.

Comment: Without an orientation of $X$, how do you give $\alpha(X)$ an orientation? If $X$ is just a plain set, $\alpha(X)$ is one too.

Comment: @DanielFischer: How do you define orientation of a set? I was defining $X$ without orientation and $\alpha(X)$ as negative orientation iff $X$ is reflected by $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\vol{vol}%
\newcommand\volhat{\widehat{\operatorname{vol}}}$You could start with the unsigned equation
$$
\vol(\alpha(X)) = \left|\det \alpha\right|\cdot\vol(X)
$$
from which we get
$$
\left|\det (\alpha\circ\beta)\right|\cdot \vol X = \vol(\alpha(\beta(X))) = \left|\det\alpha\right|\cdot\vol(\beta(X)) = \left|\det\alpha\right|\cdot\left|\det\beta\right|\cdot\vol(X)
$$
and therefore
$$
\left|\det(\alpha\circ\beta)\right| = \left|\det\alpha\cdot\det\beta\right|.
$$

Your oriented volume $\volhat(Y)$ is not well defined, since $\volhat(Y)$ for $Y=\alpha(X)$ seems to depend on properties of $\alpha$ but we also have $Y=\operatorname{id}(Y)$, so $\volhat$ can't decide the sign without knowing about the map involed.

In order to make a rigorous statement including the orientation, you first have to define some notion of an oriented set (i.e. a structure that consists of (i) the set and (ii) an orientation of the set) and then define oriented volumes for oriented sets.

---

Let me explain why you really need the notion of a set carrying an orientation:

If you want to read $\volhat(\alpha(X))$ as a map that takes the pair $(\alpha, X)$ and gives you oriented volume by looking at $\alpha$ for the sign and $X$ for the volume, you have
$$
\det(\alpha\circ\beta)\cdot\vol(X) = \volhat((\alpha\circ\beta)(X))
$$
where now $\volhat$ looks at the pair $(\alpha\circ\beta, X)$. But what you want is $\volhat(\alpha(\beta(X)))$ in the next step, where you now look at the pair $(\alpha,\beta(X))$, where everything $\beta$ does to the orientation is now lost, since $\volhat(\alpha(\beta(X))$ is only concerned about the map $\alpha$ and the *unoriented set* $\beta(X)$.

Define oriented sets and you always carry orientation from $X$ to $\beta(X)$ to $\alpha(\beta(X))$ and the problem of losing information doesn't occur anymore.

---

Let me try to do this:

> **Definition:** An *oriented set* is a pair $\widehat X=(X,\epsilon)$ where $X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is some set and $\epsilon\in\{+,-\}$ is the *orientation*. Define $\epsilon(\widehat X):=\epsilon$.
>
> Let $\mathcal O(\mathbb R^n)$ be the set of all oriented subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.
>
> **Definition:** A linear map $\alpha:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ gives rise to a map
>   \begin{align}
> \widehat\alpha:\mathcal O(\mathbb R^n) &\longrightarrow \mathcal O(\mathbb R^n), \\
> \widehat X &\longmapsto (\alpha(X), \alpha(\epsilon(\widehat X))),
> \end{align}
>   where $\alpha(\epsilon)=\epsilon$ if $\alpha$ doesn't flip the space and $\alpha(\epsilon)=-\epsilon$ if it does. Note that $\widehat{\alpha\circ\beta}=\widehat\alpha\circ\widehat\beta$.
>
> **Definition:** The *oriented volume* of an oriented set $\widehat X$ is given by
>   $$\volhat(\widehat X) := \epsilon(\widehat X)\cdot\vol(X).$$

With this definitions, we have for an oriented set $\widehat X$ and a linear map $\alpha$
$$
\volhat(\widehat\alpha(\widehat X)) = \det\alpha \cdot \volhat(\widehat X) = \alpha(+)\cdot\left|\det\alpha\right|\cdot\volhat(\widehat X).
$$

We conclude
\begin{align}
\det(\alpha\circ\beta)\cdot\volhat(\widehat X) &= \volhat((\widehat\alpha\circ\widehat\beta)(\widehat X)) = \volhat(\widehat\alpha(\widehat\beta(\widehat X)) = \det \alpha \cdot \volhat (\widehat\beta(\widehat X)) \\&= \det \alpha \cdot\det \beta \cdot\volhat(\widehat X)).
\end{align}

Comment: Please see the revised question. Note that $\widehat{\operatorname{vol}}(Y)$ is not defined but $\widehat{\operatorname{vol}}(\alpha(Y))$ is.

Comment: @Shahab, I explained why this doesn't work in my updated answer. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I understand all this, but do not know how to give meaning to oriented sets and oriented volume independently. Can you give me the definitions (independent of the notion of determinant)?

Comment: @Shahab, I made up some definitions that make this work. Can you follow what I did?

Comment: Thanks. I will put all this on my blog (with credit to you, of course).